# How to filter for two OUs using LDAP?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I'm using this to access contact information using our Yealink phones.

```
OU=Users, OU=Office2, DC=domain, DC=local
```

I get results from the `Users` OU of `Office2`, however I also need the `Office1` OU to be in the results.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could set your search base to DC=domain, DC=local and search using "(|(ou=office1)(ou=office2))" or just "(ou=users)" assuming 'ou=users' container exists under both office1 and office2.

Comment: Which one of these fields would that search string go under? I have a screenshot here of the available settings: http://i.imgur.com/18zYgbr.png